# Why does a zombie process consume a large amount of CPU resources?

Tags: linux, centos7, zombie

`pcm-memory` was found to become a zombie process in the system, consuming a significant amount of CPU resources. At the same time, the `time` field in `top` will become abnormal: this machine only has a total of 56 logical cores, so it needs to run for at least 5124519h/56 = 91509h = 3812days, while the startup time of this machine is only 308 days

```
    PID    USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    799355 root      20   0       0      0      0 Z  4259  0.0  5124519h pcm-memory
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you verify the data by looking into /proc/799355/stat ?